# Getting the highest value of an enum

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have C++ code that uses a bitset to store which values of an enum were found in my data structures (it's actually a bit more complex, but that doesn't matter for the question).

This means that when I have an enum like this:

```
enum Color
   {
     RED
   , GREEN
   , BLUE
   };
```

I want to define my bitset like this:

```
std::bitset<3>
```

Of course I don't want to hard-code the value 3.

In some cases I can simply add a 'terminator' to the enum, like this:

```
enum Color
   {
     RED
   , GREEN
   , BLUE
   , _COLOR_TERMINATOR
   };
```

And I can write this:

```
std::bitset<_COLOR_TERMINATOR>
```

But I cannot do this in all of my enums.  If I would do this on some of my enums, code-checkers (like Lint) would complain that not all enum-values are used in a switch-statement.

Is there a way to get the maximum of the values in an enum without changing something in the enum itself?  E.g. something like `std::max<Color>`?

Using Visual Studio 2013 and C++.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way of doing it.

Comment: The "terminator value" is the only (and common) approach AFAIK. Some linters allow marking code as "nolint", maybe you could do this with the enums in question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use a trait specialized for your enums to add the max defined value

```
template<class T> struct top_bound;
template<> struct top_bound<Color>{ static const size_t value = 3;};
```

and then

```
std::bitset<top_bound<Color>::value> my_bitset;
```

You still have to change the trait each time the enum changes, but you have only one explicit place to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the following, does your version of lint complain?

```
enum Color
 {
   RED
 , GREEN
 , BLUE
 , LAST_COLOR = BLUE
 };
```

This definition of `LAST_COLOR` is relatively easy to maintain (you only have to change it when you add or remove a color at the end, not when you insert or remove colors at other places, and when inserting or deleting a color forces you to change two lines they at least are consecutive lines of your code).  You then can write, for example,

```
std::bitset<LAST_COLOR + 1>
```

Alternatively, immediately after defining `enum Color`, how about

```
static const size_t _COLOR_TERMINATOR = BLUE + 1;
```